# How to connect to a implicit FTPS server with nodeJS?

Tags: node.js, express, implicit, ftps

For a project I have to connect to a FTPS server over a implicit connection.
I tried with node-ftp, because it seems that this is the only library, that supports the implicit connection.

I connect using the following code:

```
var ftpC = new FTPClient();
  ftpC.on('ready', function () {
    console.log('Connection successful!');
  });

  ftpC.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });

  console.log('Try to connect to FTP Server...');
  ftpC.connect({
    host: HOST_TO_CONNECT,
    port: 990,
    secure: 'implicit',
    user: '***',
    password: '***',
    secureOptions: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false
      // secureProtocol: 'SSLv23_method',
      // ciphers: 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256'
    }
  })
```

This code gives me everytime a timeout error. If I raise the timeout, the error comes later.
I tried in *secureOptions* to add the params *rejectUnauthorized*, *secureProtocol* and *ciphers*, as you can see. None of them is working. Everytime I get this timeout error.

In FileZilla I have no problem to connect. Everything is working fine.

Do someone have a solution for this behavior? 
Or is there another plugin for nodejs to connect to a implicit FTPS server?

Comment: Do you see anything logged if you add event listeners for the "greeting" `node-ftp` event, or the "secureConnect" `tls` event, _e.g._ `ftpC.on("greeting", function (text) {` or `ftpC.on("secureConnect", function (...)`, for getting more information?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a bug in `node-ftp`. I've created a [PR for it](https://github.com/mscdex/node-ftp/pull/171) and will update this as soon as it's been fixed.