# FTP-Sync for Visual Studio Code with implicit FTP TLS/SSL

Tags: visual-studio, ssl, visual-studio-code, ftp, ftps

I'm trying to mimic my working WinSCP FTP site on Visual Studio Code with the FTP-Sync package and I can't get this done for some reason.

Our server requires implicit FTP so my working site is `ftps://ftpwebsite.user:990` and it prompts for my user and pass which works.

This package tries to connect for a minute and then closes with no luck.

Config file:

```json
{
    "protocol": "ftps",
    "host": "ftpweb.user",
    "port": 990,
    "user": "ftpweb.user|user123",
    "pass": "**********",
    "remote": "/",
    "secure": false,
    "uploadOnSave": true,
    "passive": true,
    "debug": true,
    "privateKeyPath": null,
    "passphrase": null,
    "agent": null,
    "watch":[],
    "watchTimeout": 500,
    "allow": [],
    "ignore": [
        "\\.vscode",
        "\\.git",
        "\\.DS_Store"
    ],
    "generatedFiles": {
        "extensionsToInclude": [
            ""
        ],
        "path": ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the ftp-sync uses [Node.js node-ftp module](https://github.com/mscdex/node-ftp).

And it seems that for it to use implicit TLS/SSL, you need to set `secure` to `implicit`:

> secure - mixed - Set to true for both control and data connection encryption, 'control' for control connection encryption only, or 'implicit' for implicitly encrypted control connection (this mode is deprecated in modern times, but usually uses port 990) Default: false

See also [How to connect to a implicit FTPS server with nodeJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41221050/850848)

---

Though are you sure that you need to use the implicit mode? As even mentioned in the above documentation, the implicit mode is obsolete.